# Cant uninstall forever nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever

I installed the package [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) with

```
npm install forever -g
```

When I tried to remove with

```
npm uninstall -g forever
```

It gives me the message `up to date in 0.042s`

But I can still use the forever command line.

Tried to restart the machine already, did not work so far.

I will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: are you sure you have enough permissions ? try `npm rm -g forever`

Comment: for future reference, outside of `nvm` and `npx`, you shouldn't need to install _anything_ globally. `nvm` lets you switch node versions as needed, and `npx` lets you run anything from the local, rather than global, node_modules directory.

Comment: I have to sudo... Thank you @Taki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Uninstalling an npm package**

The command is simple as below,

```
npm uninstall <name>
```

**Note:** If you're removing a global package, any applications referencing it will crash.
Here are the options to uninstall,

```
npm uninstall <name> removes the module from node_modules, but not package.json
```

```
npm uninstall <name> --save removes it from dependencies in package.json
```

```
npm uninstall <name> --save-dev also removes it from devDependencies in package.json
```

```
npm -g uninstall <name> --save also removes it globally
```

**Checking if it is still installed**

Use the list command with the -g flag to see all packages that are installed globally:

```
npm list -g
```

To check if a specific package is installed globally, you can provide the name of package (grunt in this case) as seen below:

```
npm list -g <name>
```